# Can not deserialize instance of SaleListDTO out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: json, jackson

The issue is i'm getting this error.

I have to simulate rest service call because it's being developed now by another team.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.egencia.service.invoiceaggregator.cache.SaleListDTO out of START_ARRAY token
```

Here is my jackson mapper bean

```
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
                .json()
                .featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)                                    .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
                .failOnUnknownProperties(false)
                .build();
@JsonRootName("list")
public class SaleListDTO {
    private SaleDTO[] list;
    public SaleDTO[] getList() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setList(SaleDTO[] list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Here is the JsON file

```
{"list": [
    {
        "id": 111111,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "country": "ITA",
        "name": "Italy",
        "code": "IT"
    },...
]}
```

I have tested so many combinations but in vain. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove @JsonRootName("list").

Here is the working example :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class SaleListDTO {

    @JsonProperty("list")
    private SaleDTO[] list;



}


@Getter
@Setter
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class SaleDTO {

    private int id;
    private String currency;
    private String country;
    private String name;
    private String code;   



}
```

Test Method:

```
@Test
    public void testConversion() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        SaleListDTO dto=mapper.readValue(new File(PATH), SaleListDTO.class);
        System.out.println(dto.toString());
    }
```

Response :

```
SaleListDTO(list=[SaleDTO(id=111111, currency=EUR, country=ITA, name=Italy, code=IT), SaleDTO(id=22222, currency=IN, country=INDIA, name=CHENNAI, code=IT)])
```

Comment: Hi @Barath, from which library you're taking the annotations ?

Comment: It's from project lombok

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>